# Github Actions ##vso[task.setvariable] equivalent

Tags: github-actions

In Azure Devops, I can set a pipeline variable at runtime by echoing:

```
##vso[task.setVariable var=value]
```

How can I do the same thing in Github Workflows?

I'm not making a custom action, so I don't think outputs are relevant, I just want to pass a variable from one step to another. However, I might be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will set a `value` as an env variable named `environment_variable_name`

`echo "{environment_variable_name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_ENV`

An example on how you would use this could be

```
steps:
  - name: Set the value
    id: step_one
    run: |
      echo "action_state=yellow" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  - name: Use the value
    id: step_two
    run: |
      echo "${{ env.action_state }}" # This will output 'yellow'
```

More on this can be found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable)